# I have installed swiper from npm but it is giving me an error "TypeError: swiper.params is undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

here is my code, i am using  "^8.2.4" version of swiper

```js
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css'
import 'swiper/swiper.min.css'

export default () => {
  return (
    <Swiper
      spaceBetween={50}
      slidesPerView={3}
      onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
      onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
    >
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
  );
};
```

error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoMnq.jpg

Comment: If you want minified css you should import it like this:
import "swiper/css/bundle";

You can check in the package.json of Swiper that this CSS is already minified. 
"./css/bundle": "./swiper-bundle.min.css".

That's what probably causes your error, I have no problems with the same version ))